# Turn on/off a LED using a D-FF and a transistor

Tags: transistors, led, flipflop, ttl, drive

I'm trying to control a LED using some microcontroller and I designed a circuit using a D-FF and a transistor to handle it. It looks like this:

[image: DFF-LED]

So I can control when to turn it on or of by simply writting on the data bus as LSB of that is attached to the D pin of the D-FF.

When I reset the circuit the LED turns off successfully and also when I turn it on afterwards.

But, when trying to turn it off when it's already fired up by writting a 0 onto the data bus, it doesn't work and the led it's still turned on.

I hooked up the logic analyzer to ensure what's going and that's exactly what happened, but don't know why. The Q output should be low when writting a 0 and receive a clock pulse:

[image: DFF-timing2]

Any suggestion why the Q output remains on high level after that?

_

EDIT: How about simply inverting the LED indication and connect it to D-FF /Q output instead of Q?:

[image: DFF-LED-INVERTED]

Comment: Use a resistor (2k ?) between base and emitter of the transistor.

Comment: Showing time on the diagram woukd help heaps. Also, as clock does not reach 0 - what are the levels?

Comment: @MarcusMüller I edited main post to update the screenshot of the timing diagram. Clock pulse is 620ns width, so it should be enough to let the DFF latch the input data value, right?
That pulse is taken from the write strobe signal (inverted) from the microcontroller

Comment: @Antonio51, thanks I will try it. But what's the basis of doing that?

Comment: @RussellMcMahon I edited the main post to update the timing diagram. Now it shows that the pulse is 620ns width.
The clock reach the 0 level. The line below is from another signal (#6) which is at high level at that point.

Comment: What voltage is Vcc? The 74LS74 isn't specified to operate on anything other than 5 V, and I could believe this kind of behaviour from a chip powered by a too-low power supply.

Comment: And to answer for Antonio, their suggestion is simply good practice to make the transistor turn off faster, and (in some particularly high-gain transistors; irrelevant for most) prevent it from turning on from its own leakage.

Comment: @Hearth, Vcc level is 5V, as it's a circuit based in an old CMOS 5V MCU, so LS74 should work fine

Comment: Is there a decoupling capacitor from pin14 to pin 7? Have you properly tied off the inputs of the other part in the chip?

Comment: Does Q behave properly without the LED? Do you have an oscilloscope? The logic analyzer may be hiding some ugliness — if you have terrible layout and no bypass cap the ground bounce may be enough to affect the LSTTL with its low noise immunity for ‘0’.

Comment: @RussellH I have a 0.1uF decoupling cap next to the chip, but not directly soldered into the power pins of LS74. Now I realized that the other DFF on that LS74 is not used and pins are N.C. Could that be de problem? Should I tie the inputs of the other DFF (Set, Reset, D and C)?

Comment: @SpehroPefhany sadly, I don't have a scope to check it. This is a hobbyist project and I only have a LA and a Logic probe to check things out. About bypass cap, do you mean a basic filter cap (electrolytic) to filter the AC noise near to the power supply? I have installed a 470uF electrolytic in the circuit for that.

Comment: I mean a 0.1uF ceramic capacitor directly (as in physically close) across the power pins of the flip-flop chip.

Comment: One of Set, Reset should be high. The other should be low. The clock should be low. D can be high or low. The Qs should be  left unconnected.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany, yes I have it, right next to the chip

Comment: @RussellH, ok, I will tie them and test

Comment: The BJT will be well "locked" when output is low.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany I removed R43 from the circuit to isolate D-FF from the transistor and LED and tested it again and result was the same. D-FF didn't output Q as low even when it should, so it's not transistor or LED related.

Comment: @RussellH I tied properly (as you stated) the other unused inputs of that LS74 but result is the same. Q output remains hi even when a D input is low and a clock pulse is set.

Comment: Can you photograph the chip logo and post?

Comment: Please also photograh the circuit layout and post.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you can do (dividing by 2 for example) ...
Choose (my) R1 (> 2k) until you can do it.

[image]

Comment: I tested it adding a 2k resistor but same results. I edited main question to add another option

Comment: Don't forget the decoupling capacitor ... is it possible that this FF is "out" ?